# What is the difference between formatting and mounting a file

Tags: filesystems

From Wikipedia

**Disk formatting**

> Disk formatting is the process of preparing a data storage device such as a hard disk drive, solid-state drive, floppy disk or USB flash drive for initial use.

**Mount (computing)**

> Mounting is a process by which the operating system makes files and directories on a storage device (such as hard drive, CD-ROM, or network share) available for user to access via the computer's file system.

I don't understand how these two sentences are different

Comment: Formatting is preparing the device for **its** initial use while mounting is preparing the device for the **file system**

Comment: Does that mean mounting is performed each time a new file is created while formatting is only performed once?

Comment: Mounting is performed each time the device is made accessible to a computer (i.e. when connection) I’m sure a google search will turn up many articles explaining how each one works

Comment: I googled before I made this post but everything about formatting was a how to guide. So formatting is done on disk and mounting is done in memory?

Comment: Formatting is like preparing an ice rink for skating: letting ice freeze and polishing it and perhaps putting coloured lines on it. Mounting is like opening the ice rink to the skaters so they can use it. (Of course there are lots of things which are not good with this analogy.)

Answer (score 0):

You **format** a *device*. You **mount** a *filesystem*.

## Mounting a Filesystem

Typically, to make a device ready to be written to by the system, you'd have to do the following:

1. Physically connect the device to the system
2. (optional but recommended) Create a partition on your device
3. Create a filesystem on the device/partition
4. Mount the filesystem on the device/partition to a directory on your system's filesystem, so that you can access the filesystem of the device/partition from your system.

## Formatting a Device

Therefore, every filesystem is backed by some block storage device. The storage medium of a block storage device (e.g. a hard disk) is divided into many sections, called **sectors**. Each sector has a unique address. Whenever you write to, or read from, the device, it is done by writing/reading whole sectors. Therefore, the sector is a smallest addressable physical unit for a block storage device.

When you format a device, you are adding 'marks' onto the storage medium to mark the location of these sectors.

## Source of Confusion

Formatting has nothing to do with the filesystem, or mounting. The confusion often arise from Windows users, because on Windows, the term 'formatting' also includes the creation of the filesystem. On Windows, when you format a disk, you are also creating a filesystem on it (and Windows also automatically mount devices you connect).

> To distinguish between Window's version of 'formatting', and actual formatting, people have used the term **low-level formatting** for actual formatting, and **high-level formatting** for creating the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting a disk or partition usually means that you're actually creating or have already created a volume, and it is the volume that you are formatting. Formatting a volume is to write an empty filesystem with the initialised filesystem structures like the MFT to the volume.

Mount has the notion of putting something on top of the other. But what is considered to be on top and what is considered to be at the bottom varies.

For mount points, the mount directory and the existing directory tree is considered to be on the bottom, and you mount the volume on top of / to the directory. This is despite the mount points actually being logically higher than the volume in the driver stack and the process of interacting with files. You sometimes see people say mounting the filesystem to the mount point, like the Linux df command. This makes sense because the file system is indeed logically between the volume and the mount point.

For mounting filesystems to volumes, the filesystem is on top and the volume is below. You mount the filesystem onto the volume. It is actually logically on top of the volume because on Windows it is consulted by the I/O Manager before the volume and it is up to the file system to interact with the volume stack.

On Windows, the volume is mounted to its mount points (C:\ if the symbolic link is \DosDevices\C:) and then you mount the file system to the volume by formatting the volume. Formatting the volume with a file system causes the file system driver to mount the volume. The file system will then  mount itself to the volume every time the volume is detected 'arrives' on the system so long as it has been formatted with that file system because the file system driver detects its filesystem on the volume.

Answer (score -2):

Formatting is usually done **ONCE** during the lifetime of the hard drive.
The hard drive is written to, wiping away anything that was on it previously, so that it can be accepted as a **filesystem**.

Mounting usually happens every time the system has been restarted.  It allows the operating system to access the hard drive as a **filesystem**.  Mounting a drive does **NOT** alter the hard drive, although once a filesystem has been mounted it can be modified (unless it was mounted read-only) by typical filesystem operations like creating a directory/folder, creating files, modifying files, etc ....

Mounting tells the operating system which filesystem type (ext3, ext4, HFS+, NTFS, ZFS ...) the hard drive is allowing the OS kernel to map the virtual filesystem functions to the real filesystem functions.